# Is "logstash-" a mandatory prefix of indices in kibana?

Tags: indexing, elasticsearch, logstash, prefix, kibana

If I put messages on index "[logstash-example-]YYYY.MM.DD" then kibana can show the log message in charts but if it's on "[example-]YYYY.MM.DD" then it won't find it. 
(curl query gives back the correct result in latter case)

According to documentation it should work:
"For example [web-]YYYY.MM.DD,[mail-]YYYY.MM.DD Please also note that indices should rollover at midnight UTC."

(Elasticsearch 1.3.4, Kibana 3.1.0)

Comment: It's not mandatory, you can put any name. There must be another thing

Answer (score 0):

You have to modify your kibana dashboard setting

1. Click `Configure dashboarad` in Kibana on Right Top.
2. Select `Index` tab.
3. Modify `Index pattern` to your new index pattern. For example: [example-]YYYY.MM.DD

Hope this can help you.

Comment: Yes, I did exactly this but log message didn't show up even though the query is just "*" in kibana and also filter doesn't filter it out.